# How to SELECT, modify and INSERT data in Influx DB?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I'm new to InfluxDB. I currently have two databases in influx. I now want to copy certain data points from a measurement in the database1, then I want to introduce a couple field sets manually and modify the few field values that I copied and finally insert the changed data points in database2 under a different measurement.

I can use the select into statement however that will not allow me to make changes to the datapoint.
If I use the Insert command I will have to type all the field sets and tag sets individually.

I have a solution that I can use python and query the data points and manipulate the data then insert it back. However that will be a lengthy process.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Comment: I don' t think so. The best way to is to write an automated script like you did in Python. You could of course use `jq` `curl` `awk`, Regex but it would end up being just another automated script written in Bash and not in Python.

Comment: @Shan Desai

Thanks. I guess then I better get to work on my script.

I had one more question. I know that a data point is defined using three things.
1.timestamp
2.measurement
3.tag set

however we also have field keys and field values. If I use a tag value in the where clause or a time duration it works but why doesn't Influx allow us to use field values in the where clause? Any idea?

Comment: You can use that `fields` to poll the information. Maybe it is wise to create a new question and I will answer it for you there.

Comment: Here is the [docs for using fields as query](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-do-i-query-data-with-an-identical-tag-key-and-field-key).

Comment: Thanks Shan-Desai. I stand corrected and we can use fields to poll information. I was unable to do so due to a simple case of double quotations. The field key was two separate words so had to use quotations for it to work.